# Error Code 1064 MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need to know what i am doing wrong right now in this. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

```
mysql>host/"localhost";
mysql>port=3306;
      database=ml 
      username=****
      password=********
      clientamount=30;
```

I need to know how to fix the first line can anybody tell me?

Comment: That error is 'you have an error in your SQL syntax'. What query are you performing?

Comment: Err, next time you should think about obfuscating your actual connection's username/password when posting to a public forum.

Comment: Wrong thing is that you have no clue what are you doing. Read some tutorials first.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I see; that's the command you are issuing. Sorry, didn't understand. I think the command you are using is a shell command, intended to invoke the MySQL client, not a MySQL command.

Comment: i am not sure. i am trying to make a habbo retro

Comment: What on earth is a habbo retro?